# Bounty custom message box is too wide

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

A picture says it all.

The box moves horizontally depending on where the cursor moves to while entering text in the box.

I am using Firefox 31.0 on Fedora 20 / KDE.

[image: Bounty custom message box, left and right clipped]